# Writing JSON object to file writes unwanted character

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to write JSON object to file which consists of JSONArray. Before writing this object to TXT file I check each structure printing it in console. For example I got this out put:

```
{"splittedHostEnteredString":["cześć.","w"],"foreignLanguage":"cześć","historyToWord":"cześć. w","mainLanguage":"jak","country":0}
```

In list I have for example 10 objects like above and each of them prints correctly. Problem is when I try to write ArrayList which has all objects as strings. File writes also but after it, there are some additional characters - "\" in all structure. I convert object to string using GSON library. Below is the output after saving file:

```
{"names":["{\"splittedHostEnteredString\":[\"cześć.\",\"każdym\"],\"foreignLanguage\":\"jak\",\"historyToWord\":\"cześć. w każdym razie\",\"mainLanguage\":\"z\",\"country\":0}","{\"splittedHostEnteredString\":[\"cześć.\",\"w\"],\"foreignLanguage\":\"cześć\",\"historyToWord\":\"cześć. w\",\"mainLanguage\":\"jak\",\"country\":0}"]}
```

This is my code:

```
public void saveListOfExistingObjectsInApplicationToOneFileJson()
{
    String filename = "configuration.txt";
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
    try {
        myFile.createNewFile();

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        try {

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < listOfSavedFiles.size(); i++)
            {
                array.put(listOfSavedFiles.get(i));
            }

            obj.put("names", array);
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
            String tmpStringToWrite = obj.toString();

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            try {
                stream.write(tmpStringToWrite.getBytes());
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }           

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Problem is when I try to write ArrayList which has all objects as strings" - this is an answer. Add objects, not strings.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the problem. Little thing but does a lot.